# For element in list of tuples, return other element in tuple

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples

Below is my code for a function that searches a list of tuples called pairs. Each tuple in the list is comprised of two elements.

The element given in the function (called item) could be in the 0 or 1 position of the tuple, but all the tuples in the list are composed of only 2 elements.

```
pairs = [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f'),('c','a')]

def connections(pairs, item):
    output = ''
    for j in pairs:
        if item in j:
            output = output + str(j)
    return (output)
```

Right now this code will pull out the entire tuple(s) that have the item within them.

I'd like to change this code to only return the other element in the tuple and to return it as a string instead of a tuple.

Comment: What is the *exact* output you are expecting, and what are you currently getting that is not meeting your expectations?

Comment: I suppose you're looking for something equivalent to `reduce(lambda total, current: total + current[1], pairs, ''")` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
def connection(pairs, item):
    return ''.join([p[1-p.index(item)] for p in pairs if item in p])
```

Here's some sample output:

```
>>> connection([('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f'),('c','a')], 'a')
'bc'
```

Comment: The other solutions here are fine, but this is the most readable solution. Nice work!

Comment: Somewhat faster alternative to `p[1-p.index(item)]` would be `p[p[0] == item]`.

Comment: @mwm314 it's a good solution, but definitely not the most readable one

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for membership, check for equality.

```
def connections(pairs, item):
    output = ''
    for j in pairs:
        if item == j[0]:
            output += j[1]
        elif item == j[1]:
            output += j[0]
    return output
```

Note that I've streamlined the concatenation into augmented assignment and removed the unnecessary `str()` calls, as they are already strings. Or you could do it as follows:

```
def connections(pairs, item):
    return ''.join(j[0] if item==j[1] else j[1] if item==j[0] else '' for j in pairs)
```

Comment: Alternative streamlined approach to choosing: `(set(j) - {item}).pop()` This assumes the pairs are never a duplicated value of course. Could even integrate it into loop: `for j in map(set, pairs):` `if item in j:` `output += (j - {item}).pop()`. Not going to claim it's more efficient, prettier or anything (if it were, I'd make it an answer), just giving MTOWTDI. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger - That `set` strategy doesn't work for duplicate pairs (as you mention), and it wouldn't work if the item doesn't match either element, either.

Comment: That's why it still needs the membership test, which I left in. Alternatively, you do the subtraction first, pop, then check for whether the set was emptied by that: `for j in map(set, pairs):`, `j -= {item}`, `other = j.pop()`, `if not j: output += other` (which still assumes pairs don't have the same value twice, like all `set` based solutions).

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! Unfortunately I forgot to specify I want some kind of delimiter between the strings, for example output could be "a, d" or just a,d or even a(space)d. How could I apply this to the output?

Comment: @Ouwan12 - See where it says `''.join(...`? That `''` is the delimiter. `', '.join(...` or `','.join(...` or `' '.join(...` etc.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I see now, I was running the less streamlined code but now I see. I hope to one day be so pythonic! Thank you again for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
pairs = [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f'),('c','a')]

def connections(pairs, item):
    output = ''
    for j in pairs:
        if item in j:
            index = 1-j.index(item)
            output = output + str(j[index])
    return (output)

print(connections(pairs, 'c'))
```

Output:

```
da
```